# Cannot Generate .tar File

Tags: windows-10, powershell, tar

How do I make a `.tar` from current directory tree in Win10? Trying `tar -c Archive.tar *` and getting `tar: Failed to open '\\.\tape0'`.

```
C:\>tar -h
tar(bsdtar): manipulate archive files
First option must be a mode specifier:
  -c Create  -r Add/Replace  -t List  -u Update  -x Extract
Common Options:
  -b #  Use # 512-byte records per I/O block
  -f <filename>  Location of archive (default \\.\tape0)
  -v    Verbose
  -w    Interactive
Create: tar -c [options] [<file> | <dir> | @<archive> | -C <dir> ]
  <file>, <dir>  add these items to archive
  -z, -j, -J, --lzma  Compress archive with gzip/bzip2/xz/lzma
  --format {ustar|pax|cpio|shar}  Select archive format
  --exclude <pattern>  Skip files that match pattern
  -C <dir>  Change to <dir> before processing remaining files
  @<archive>  Add entries from <archive> to output
List: tar -t [options] [<patterns>]
  <patterns>  If specified, list only entries that match
Extract: tar -x [options] [<patterns>]
  <patterns>  If specified, extract only entries that match
  -k    Keep (don't overwrite) existing files
  -m    Don't restore modification times
  -O    Write entries to stdout, don't restore to disk
  -p    Restore permissions (including ACLs, owner, file flags)
bsdtar 3.3.2 - libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.5.f-ipp
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> -f <filename>  Location of archive (default \\.\tape0)
> ```

You missed `-f` so `tar` used the default location (treating `Archive.tar` as a file to be archived). Your command should be like

```
tar -cf Archive.tar *
```

although I don't know PowerShell's rules of usage of `*`. You may try to pass `--` just before `*` to make `tar` stop parsing options, I hope your `tar` understands this. This is in case `*` returns something which initial part looks like options for `tar`.

Comment: Can you past full command line as example?

Comment: `tar: Can't launch external program: bzip2` same without -j and tar extension. M$ - Grrr. `tar -cf Archive www` worked.

Comment: Yes file issue resolved but still doesn't generate bz2 format, just tar packed format. M$ introduced tar in Mar'18. tar -h implies bz2 is available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83417/discussion-between-kamil-maciorowski-and-flywire).